# Extract "name" from the list of dicts in Ansible

Tags: ansible, json-query

I have the following dictionary:

```
"dict": [ {   "name": "a",   "surname": "b" }, {   "name": "c",   "surname": "d" }, {   "name": "e",   "surname": "f" } ]
```

I am trying to extract just "name" values into one list like this one:

> names_list: ["a","c","e"]

It should be very simple but I'm not getting the result.
This is what I tried:

```
- set_fact: 
    names_list: "{{ dict | json_query('[*].name') }}"
```

and also:

```
- set_fact: 
    names_list: "{{ dict | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

but I'm getting either "none" or "ansible undefined".

What I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Rename the variable *dict*.

Details: In Ansible 2.14.3, Python 3.9.16, jinja version = 3.1.2 both options work as expected

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        names_list1: "{{ dict|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
        names_list2: "{{ dict|json_query('[*].name') }}"
```

give

```yaml
  names_list1: [a, c, e]
  names_list2: [a, c, e]
```

But, I got the warning:

> [WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: dict

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dict:
      - {name: a, surname: b}
      - {name: c, surname: d}
      - {name: e, surname: f}

    # names_list1: "{{ dict|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
    # names_list2: "{{ dict|json_query('[*].name') }}"
    
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        names_list1: "{{ dict|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
        names_list2: "{{ dict|json_query('[*].name') }}"
    
    - debug:
        var: names_list1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: names_list2|to_yaml
```

Comment: We have older versions, Ansible 2.11.11 , Python 3.6

Comment: Actually this works, but not with set_fact like I tried first, but declared as variable, and I used instead "dict" some other name. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

your "dict" above is a list of dictionaries.
you are trying to create a new list with just the names.
Try

```
names_list: "{{ names_list | d([]) + [item.name] }}"
with_items: dict
```

Comment: I tried but getting Ansible undefined:
ok: [localhost] => (item=dict) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "names_list": "[AnsibleUndefined]"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "dict"
}

Comment: @piercjs Undefined variables no clarity on what you are suggesting here.